# Using groups in Go Regex with Or |

Tags: regex, go

Is there a way in Go Regex if I have (a)|(b) to start groups for b also with 0 ? how would I do that?

```
re := regexp.MustCompile(
   `<(\$)([a-zA-Z0-9]+):([a-zA-Z0-9]+):([a-zA-Z0-9]+)>|{(@)([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)}`)
```

and iterate over with

```
for _, v := range re.FindAllSubmatchIndex([]byte(str), -1) {
  ...
}
```

How do I "normalize" groups (indexes)? so the (@) is also group 0?

Can i use groupnames with the same names?

Comment: That does not seem possible as Go regex does not support [branch reset groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html). Use some PCRE library if you need it badly.

Comment: Thanks, and thanks for the technical term.

Comment: If you'll make it an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go regex engine is [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax), and infortunately it does not support the feature you are looking for, namely, a [branch reset group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html).

There are PCRE library ports for Go if you need it by all means. Here is a [`package pcre` library](https://godoc.org/github.com/glenn-brown/golang-pkg-pcre/src/pkg/pcre), for example. Once added, you can use

```
(?|<(\$)([a-zA-Z0-9]+):([a-zA-Z0-9]+):([a-zA-Z0-9]+)>|{(@)([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)})
^^^                                                  ^                    ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/liXo9y/1).